# Finding rows where two values not equal, with nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm interested to know what the common practices are for this situation.

You need to find all rows where two columns do not match, both columns are nullable (Exclude where both columns are NULL). None of these methods will work:

```
WHERE A <> B --does not include any NULLs

WHERE NOT (A = B) --does not include any NULLs

WHERE (A <> B OR A IS NULL OR B IS NULL) --includes NULL, NULL
```

Except this...it does work, but I don't know if there is a performance hit...

```
WHERE COALESCE(A, '') <> COALESCE(B, '')
```

Lately I've started using this logic...it's clean, simple and works...would this be considered the common way to handle it?:

```
WHERE IIF(A = B, 1, 0) = 0
--OR
WHERE CASE WHEN A = B THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit painful, but I would advise direct boolean logic:

```
where (A <> B) or (A is null and B is not null) or (A is not null and B is null)
```

or:

```
where not (A = B or A is null and B is null)
```

It would be much simpler if SQL Server implemented `is distinct from`, the ANSI standard, `NULL`-safe operator.

If you use `coalesce()`, a typical method is:

```
where coalesce(A, '') <> coalesce(B, '')
```

This is used because `''` will convert to most types.

Comment: The second form above is tricky but functional since if A=B, then neither A or B are null, and if A is not null but B is null, it is still not a true statement. Logically, it might be better if the "A is NULL and B is NULL" were inside parentheses, but it isn't functionally necessary.

Comment: the two first tips are better coz it gets the best performance. If you're using a function like coalesce then indexes can be used defective or can't be used.

Comment: What is your opinion on using the IIF method? Seems simple and readable and handles it well. But I'm not sure about performance.

Comment: @chadwin . . . `IIF()` is a Microsoft extension to be compatible with MS Access -- which is, let's just say, not my favorite "database".  If you are going to use conditional logic, use `CASE`.

Comment: That's just preference. What my question was, what is your opinion on using the IIF or CASE logic vs using your recommendations above. What are the down sides? Because to me, using IIF or CASE is much easier to read.

Comment: @chadwin . . . I think most people find that `AND`/`OR`/`NOT` are sufficient for boolean expressions, so extending the "language" to include `CASE` is really a complication.  The one time to use `CASE` is when you have to depend on the order of evaluation, such as when changing types and validating data before the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ?

for example if i want to get all a and b that is not a=b and exclude all null values of a and b

```
select a, b from tableX where a is not null and b is not null
except
select a,b from tableX where a=b
```